# Variables in different navigation stack

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdictionary

Sorry if my question does not match the title, but i think it does:
I have an app with a navigation controller and 3 views. It's an app where you connect to a server and talk with friends.
The thing is, my rootViewController, the login screen, calls the second view witch is the friends list. clicking in a friend on the list takes you to the third view, the chat screen itself.
I wanted to, when the user logs in (rootview), to store the user name used in a variable, so i could use it on the third view, the chat screen, so when he sends a message it can have his name on it, and while retrieving info from server, i can use his name as a parameter too.
By the way, is SQLite the best way to save messages and users? I am afraid of Core Data =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep things loosely coupled I would consider just passing along the `userName` when instantiating each `UIViewController` sub class. (Makes unit testing easier as well)

e.g.

```
 // LoginViewController -> user logs in
 FriendsViewController *friendsViewController = [[FriendsViewController alloc] initWithUserName:userName];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:friendsViewController];
 [friendsViewController release]; friendsViewController = nil;

 // FriendsViewController -> user selects a friend
 ChatViewController *chatViewController = [[ChatViewController alloc] initWithUserName:userName];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:chatViewController];
 [chatViewController release]; chatViewController = nil;
```

Don't be afraid of core data there are plenty of excellent books out there.

Comment: Thanks, i just discovered how to use the app delegate to use a var i set there.
In this method you wrote, is there a "initWithPassword" for example?

Comment: That's normally considered bad practice as you are just creating a global variable.

Comment: `initWithUserName` would have been a custom method that you would have had to write and therefore so would you `initWithPassword` method.

Answer (score 0):

Core data is not that bad.  [This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) is the guide I used to get started with Core Data.  Once you wrap your head around how everything works it really isn't that bad.

If you wanted to you *could* use SQLite, but it's a lot of code.  Core Data is much simpler to use.